# Sum Values based on Distinct Guids

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am having trouble getting the SUM of a column of values in SSRS.

My SQL query returns something like the following:

ID               Total
Guid1      4
Guid2      6
Guid3      1
Guid2      6
Guid4      6
Guid1      4

I have it grouped in my SSRS Report so it appears like this:

ID               Total
Guid1      4
Guid2      6
Guid3      1
Guid4      6

I need the sum of the Total column, but it wants to sum the ungrouped set of values instead of the grouped set. So I get

```
Sum(Total) = 27
```

But I WANT

```
Sum(DISTINCT? Guid Totals) = 17
```

I've tried the solutions that can be found on this page, with no luck: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3c2626d8-e835-4bba-b946-7d6796e9c617/sum-distinct?forum=sqlreportingservices

I've also tried to add code behind the scenes that stores the distinct ids in a hashtable, and if it's not in the hashtable, add it to a global total; which I call from each row of the table, and then display the global total at the bottom, but that's not working either.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. use invisible table put your dataset in without grouping, and get SUM.
2. modify your query in new dataset, select sum(total) from table

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure you can Sum the grouped field in ssrs.

```
=SUM(MAX(Fields!value.value,"GuidGroupName"))
```

Comment: Since I want this SUM at the bottom of the Totals column, I have to create a row outside the group -- thus, it complains when I try to add the Group name in the SUM function...